# scala FoldRight function on scala List

Tags: list, scala

I want to implement a function that takes a list eg List(3,4,5) and return the list where each element is incremented by n eg List(3+n, 4+n, 5+n) -
how can I write this functions using foldRight and what will be its time-complexity

eg list1 = List(3,4,5) 
define func(list1,2)  gives - List(5,6,9)

Answer (score 5):

Idiomatically this is the use case for `map`:

```
List(3, 4, 5).map(_ + 2) == List(5, 6, 7)
```

However, it could be written using `foldRight`:

```
List(3, 4, 5).foldRight(List.empty[Int]) { (n, acc) =>
  (n + 2) :: acc
}
```

This will have a time complexity of O(n).  `foldRight` is a linear operation and prepending to a `scala.collection.List` is constant time.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure why you want to use a foldRight

This is much better suited to map, ie

```
List(3,4,5).map(_+2) == List(5,6,7)
```

Comment: You must have meant `map`. `foreach` is only for Actions that produce `Unit` and the result is always `Unit` and not `List[A]`